# Embedding a hex value in a .jpg or .png file that doesn't impact display?

Tags: image-processing

Is there a location inside the .jpg or .png where I can put an arbitrary 32-bit value method for embedding a 32-bit value inside that will not be visible in the image (but would change the hash of the image file.)

Comment: Sure, in the comment. Add it with `exiftool`, `jhead` or ImageMagick.

Comment: You can often just append it to the end of the file and viewers will ignore it - though some may discard it, so don't do that with anything precious that you want to be certain of retrieving later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

You can do that by adding a comment. If you want a technique that works with both JPEG and PNG and doesn't recompress your image data, I would suggest `exiftool`.

You can add a comment like this to JPEG or PNG:

```
exiftool -Comment=32768 a.jpg
exiftool -Comment=32768 a.png
```

You can retrieve the comment along with all other information using:

```
exiftool a.jpg
```

Or, you can get just the comment and its value with:

```
exiftool -Comment a.jpg   
Comment                         : 32768
```

Or, if parsing in a shell script, you can get the unadorned values like this:

```
exiftool -Comment -s -s -s a.jpg
32768
```

**Original Answer**

You can put a number or comment in a file with `jhead` like this:

```
jhead -cl "32768" a.jpg
Modified: a.jpg
```

Then read it back, with jhead:

```
jhead a.jpg
File name    : a.jpg
File size    : 49732 bytes
...
...
Comment      : 32768   <--- HERE IT IS
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, does that work with .png as well?

Comment: I have updated my answer to handle both PNG and JPEG. Please have another look.